# titleformat and parttoc

Tags: titlesec, parts, titletoc, minitoc

I would like to have a parttoc on the first page of the part but I would like to be able to change the style of the part title. Can someone help me please ?

I need to run this :

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{chemist}

%%%Gestion du Français et des accents
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}

%%%Interligne
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}

%%%Page Blanche
\newcommand\myemptypage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{0}
    \newpage
    }

%%%Gestion graphique
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%Mise en page des sommaires
\usepackage{titletoc,titlesec}
\usepackage{minitoc}

%%%En-tete et pied de page
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\,$|$\,\pageref{LastPage}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%%%Mise en forme table des titres
%Titre des parties
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
%\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\normalfont\scshape\bfseries\LARGE}{\rule[3pt]{0.15\linewidth}{3pt}\quad Chapitre~\thepart \quad\rule[3pt]{0.15\linewidth}{3pt}}{20pt}{}[]

%Titre des chapitres
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\LARGE\scshape\centering}
    {\parttitle}{}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

%Titre des sections
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thepart.\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\Large\scalefont{1.1}\scshape\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}

%Titre des sous-sections
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
    {\normalfont\Large\scshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}

%%%Mise en page des sommaires
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\hrulefill}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0pt \hfill\kern0pt}

%Partie dans le sommaire
\titlecontents{part}[60pt]{\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont\scshape\bfseries\contentslabel[Chapitre~\thecontentslabel]{60pt}}{}{}
\contentsfinish

%Chapitre  dans le sommaire
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]
    {\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont\bfseries\scshape\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{100pt}}{}{}
    {\normalsize\normalfont\hrulefill\thecontentspage}{}{}
\contentsfinish

%Section  dans le sommaire
\titlecontents{section}[30pt]
    {\fontsize{14}{15}\selectfont\scshape\contentslabel{30pt}}{}{}
    {\normalsize\hrulefill\thecontentspage}{}{}
\contentsfinish

%Sous-section dans le sommaire
\titlecontents{subsection}[40pt]
    {\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont\contentslabel{40pt}}{}{}
    {\normalsize\hrulefill\normalfont\thecontentspage}{}{}
\contentsfinish

%Sous-sous-section dans le sommaire
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[50pt]
    {\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont\contentslabel{50pt}}{}{}
    {\normalsize\hrulefill\normalfont\thecontentspage}{}{}
\contentsfinish

%Changer titre du sommaire
\addto\captionsfrench{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}
    {Table des matières}}

\renewcommand{\beforeparttoc}{\empty}
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{\vskip50pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\doparttoc[n]
\tableofcontents

\part{Name of part 1}

\part{Name of part 2}
\parttoc
\chapter{This is the Chapter 1}
    \section{Section 1}
        \subsection{Subsection 1}
        \subsection{Subsection 2}
        \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \section{Section 2}
        \subsection{Subsection 1}
        \subsection{Subsection 2}
        \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \section{Section 3}
        \subsection{Subsection 1}
        \subsection{Subsection 2}
        \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \section*{Section 4 not in TOC}

\end{document}
```

and be able to use

```
%\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\normalfont\scshape\bfseries\LARGE}{\rule[3pt]{0.15\linewidth}{3pt}\quad Chapitre~\thepart \quad\rule[3pt]{0.15\linewidth}{3pt}}{20pt}{}[]
```

to have the mixte of this style with a parttoc below

[image]

And not this style title

[image]

Comment: In my experience, titlesec, titletoc and minitoc do not work very well together. Plus, I think that minitoc is not maintained anymore.